# Finding the difference between JavaScript datetimes

Tags: javascript, datetime, formatting

So I want my code in javascript to compare the current date-time with the date-time of a post. Then if the difference is only in hours, then I want it to display : Posted x hours ago.
But if it is in years, months or days, then I want it to display differently for example : Posted 5 days ago, Posted 3 years ago.

I did this logic in php, but now I have to convert it into javascript. Here is the php code I wrote :

```
$dateofmessage = date_create($posts['date_time']);
  date_default_timezone_set("{$_GET['userTimezone']}");
  $date11 = date("y-m-d H:i:s");
  date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
  $date22 = date("y-m-d H:i:s");
  if ($date11 > $date22) {
    $date1 = date_create($date11);
  $date2 = date_create($date22);
    $diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
    $differenceToAddOrSub = $diff->format("%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds");
    $changeddate = date_add($dateofmessage, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$differenceToAddOrSub"));
  } elseif ($date22 > $date11) {
    $date1 = date_create($date11);
  $date2 = date_create($date22);
    $diff = date_diff($date2, $date1);
    $differenceToAddOrSub = $diff->format("%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds");
    $changeddate = date_sub($dateofmessage, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$differenceToAddOrSub"));
  }

if (date_format($date1, "Y") == date_format($changeddate, "Y")) {

    if (date_format($date1, "d") == date_format($changeddate, "d") && date_format($date1, "m") == date_format($changeddate, "m")) {

      $time = date_format($changeddate, "h:i a");

      if ($filetype == "null") {
        echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><p class='post'>$post</p></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
      }

      if ($filetype == "video") {
        echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><video style='width:100%;' autoplay controls src='$pic_or_vid'></video></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
      }

      if ($filetype == "image") {
        echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><img style='width:100%;' src='$pic_or_vid'></img></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
      }

      if ($filetype == "textImage") {
        echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><p class='post'>$post</p><img style='width:100%;' src='$pic_or_vid'></img></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
      }

      if ($filetype == "textVideo") {
        echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><p class='post'>$post</p><video style='width:100%;' autoplay controls src='$pic_or_vid'></video></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
      }

    } else {
      $changeddatee = date_format($changeddate, "y-m-d H:i:s");

      $date = date( "M jS", strtotime($changeddatee));
      $time = date_format($changeddate, "h:i a");

      if ($filetype == "null") {
        echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time $date</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><p class='post'>$post</p></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
      }

      if ($filetype == "video") {
        echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time $date</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><video style='width:100%;' autoplay controls src='$pic_or_vid'></video></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
      }

      if ($filetype == "image") {
        echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time $date</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><img style='width:100%;' src='$pic_or_vid'></img></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
      }

      if ($filetype == "textImage") {
        echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time $date</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><p class='post'>$post</p><img style='width:100%;' src='$pic_or_vid'></img></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
      }

      if ($filetype == "textVideo") {
        echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time $date</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><p class='post'>$post</p><video style='width:100%;' autoplay controls src='$pic_or_vid'></video></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
      }
    }




} else {

  $changeddatee = date_format($changeddate, "y-m-d H:i:s");
  $date = date( "M jS Y", strtotime($changeddatee));
  $time = date_format($changeddate, "h:i a");

  if ($filetype == "null") {
    echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time $date</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><p class='post'>$post</p></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
  }

  if ($filetype == "video") {
    echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time $date</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><video style='width:100%;' autoplay controls src='$pic_or_vid'></video></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
  }

  if ($filetype == "image") {
    echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time $date</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><img style='width:100%;' src='$pic_or_vid'></img></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
  }

  if ($filetype == "textImage") {
    echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time $date</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><p class='post'>$post</p><img style='width:100%;' src='$pic_or_vid'></img></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
  }

  if ($filetype == "textVideo") {
    echo "<div class='post-div' id='$id'><p class='time'>$time $date</p><h1 class='title'>$title</h1><div class='sender'>Posted by : $username</div><div class='like_buttons'><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-up' onclick='community_like(true, $id)'></button><span id='likes_$id' class='like-dislike'>$likes</span><button class='likes fas fa-thumbs-down' onclick='community_like(false, $id)'></button><span class='like-dislikes' id='dislike_$id'>$dislikes</span></div><p class='post'>$post</p><video style='width:100%;' autoplay controls src='$pic_or_vid'></video></div><div class='comments'><p class='see_all_comments' onclick='commentsAppear($id, $communityid)'>See all comments</p></div>";
  }

}

}

}
```

Please help, I have a lot of trouble with date times as well as javascript!

Comment: May be you should convert date to timestamp and switch between timestamp intervals to display the unit

Comment: I would recommend using a date library like `date-fns` and use their built in methods like [formatDistance](https://date-fns.org/v2.21.1/docs/formatDistance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)?

You entire code from above might be replaced with just:

`moment(*any valid date*).fromNow()`

Some examples:

```js
const year = moment("2011-10-31", "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow()
console.log(year)

const day = moment().startOf('day').fromNow()
console.log(day)

const hour = moment().subtract(1, 'hour').fromNow()
console.log(hour)

const now = moment().subtract(1, 'second').fromNow()
console.log(now)

const yourJsDate = new Date(2021,3,15) // or any valid date as a string
const momentDate = moment(yourJsDate).fromNow()
console.log(momentDate)

const timezone = moment("2021-04-05 12:40:00 -07:30", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z").fromNow() // UTC -7h30min
console.log(timezone)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi! I have a question, about Moment.js, If I want to do moment("2020-04-05 12:40:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS").fromAmericaTimeNow. Can I do something like this?

Comment: Yes you can achive that by using `Z` in format and adding `+/-HH:mm` at the end of the date string. I've added an example in snippet above.

Comment: I have a question, about moment.js, I wrote this code but it doesn't seem to work : 


```
offset = moment().utcOffset();
date_time = "2021-04-28 13:00:00"; 
            d = moment([date_time]).subtract(offset, "minute");
            moment(d, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS").fromNow();
``` It keeps saying that it has been 4 months, but that isn't true

Comment: Why did you wrap `date_time` in array (`moment([date_time])`)?